# How to pass checkbox values to database by using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have no idea how to pass the values and to insert into database

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="checkbox">
        <?php echo form_checkbox('type[]', 'type1'); ?>Type 1
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <?php echo form_checkbox('type[]', 'type2'); ?>Type 2
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <?php echo form_checkbox('type[]', 'type3'); ?>Type 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model view

```
$data = array(
        'type' => $this->input->post('type[]')
        );

    $insert = $this->db->insert('parents', $data);
    return $insert;
```

Lets say I checked type1 and type2, i found that only 0 is inserted into the database.
How can I correct it?

Comment: first of all, you shouldn't use post data directly in model. You have to prepare data in controller itself before passing it to model.

Comment: You will get multiple values from type. How are you storing in db? in sub-table?

Comment: You are getting multiple values like 'type1','type2'. Are you storing as comma separated?

Comment: it can be a solution thanks!

Comment: can I use space be the string to be imploded?

Comment: yes you can use `" "` instead of comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing as comma separated value in single column, then change your code as :

```
$type = $this->input->post('type');

$data = array(

        'type' => implode(",", $type);       
 );
```

But storing in one column is not good practice. It's just temporary solution. You have to store in separate table.

Answer (score -1):

View:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="ward[]" value="MALE WARD">MALE WARD<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="ward[]" value="FEMALE WARD">FEMALE WARD<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="ward[]" value="CHILDREN WARD">CHILDREN WARD<br/>
```

Controller:

`$this->model_name->your_function();`

Model:

```
$variable = serialize($this->input->post('ward'));
$data = array(
     'section' => $variable
     );

$this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
```